# Make Default Start Date Range on Vue-2 Datepicker?

Tags: vue.js, date-range

Ihave datepicker using Vue2-Datepicker this is my component looks like

```
<date-picker
 v-model="closingRange"
 range
 valueType="format"
 :default-value="new Date()"
 :disabled-date="disabledBefore"
></date-picker>
```

and called Methods disbaledBefore

```
disabledBefore(date) {
 let dayBefore = this.$moment(this.firstDateIfNull).format(
                "YYYY-MM-DD"
            );
 const beforeToday = new Date(dayBefore);
       beforeToday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return date < beforeToday; // Assume < 25 May Not Selected
}
```

how to auto select 26 May on start date of data range and cannot change. so user just can change end date.

Answer (score 0):

just like this:

```
<date-picker
 v-model="closingRange"
 range
 valueType="format"
 :default-value="new Date()"
 :disabled-date="disabledBefore"
 :min-date="minDate"
></date-picker>

<script>
import { formatDate } from "@/utils/date";
export default {
  name: "index",
  props: {
    label: String,
    value: [String, Object, Date, Number],
    minDate: {
      type: [String, Date, Number],
      default: () => {
        return new Date(1970, 1, 1);
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```